# How to write randomForest2Rules() function in R

Tags: r, random-forest

Here is my code:

```
library(randomForest)
library(rattle)

##Classification
##
data(iris)

set.seed(71)
iris.rf <- randomForest(Species ~ ., data=iris)
print(iris.rf)
printRandomForests(iris.rf,1:5)

randomForest2Rules(iris.rf,1:5)
```

In this last line, I got an error message:

> Error in if (var.class == "character" | var.class == "factor" |
> var.class ==  :    argument is of length zero

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks.

Comment: Someone had the same issue a while back here: https://r-help.stat.math.ethz.narkive.com/qdRebFx1/r-randomforest2rules  They suggest just using the outputs of `printRandomForests`

Comment: From stepping through the stack, this is a genuine bug in `rattle::randomForest2Rules` that should be reported. It arises from a nested call to `getRFRuleSet`, which does not properly handle the `split var` column of trees. `split var` lists the variable used to split the node and is 0 if the node is terminal. These 0 entries are improperly handled as they are used to subset a vector of the variables present in the RF model (`tr.vars`). Subsetting `tr.vars[0]` returns a zero-length vector which cannot be compared causing the condition in the `if` to fail and trigger the error you see.